# YouTube API 'The user is not enabled for live streaming' while the user is

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

While making a request to create a new broadcast, I get this error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "reason": "liveStreamingNotEnabled",
    "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://www.youtube.com/features"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming."
 }
}
```

But the user is enabled! They make streams on regular basis, and I don't know how to solve this. All users of my app are doing OK with this, but two specific users get this error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using service account for it? for the authorization?

Comment: @KENdi What do you mean saying 'service'?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @KENdi service accounts dont work with the YouTube api so they are not using a service account.

Comment: @Ngoral could you specify your question a little? Are you using OAuth 2? What identification flow are you using? How exactly are users using your app?

Answer (score 4):

> The YouTube Live Streaming API lets you **create, update, and manage live events** on YouTube. Using the API, you can schedule events (broadcasts) and associate them with video streams, which represent the actual broadcast content.

The main intent of the YouTube Live Streaming API is to allow you to create, update and manage your events programmatic via the API.  There for it would make sense for Google to insist that the authenticating account would have live streaming enabled.

I suggest you check that it is enabled for us with the API. Remember that the YouTube Api authentication is channel based so you may need to check what channel you have authenticated with. If the user has more the one maybe you are looking at one that does not have live streaming enabled. [How to enable Live streaming](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/0xoKC9YWEyQ/discussion)

While I do agree it seams strange if all you are going to do is list things that you would need to have live streaming enabled this appears to be the way the API works.

I have logged this as an issue / feature request.   [Live Streaming API: live streaming not enabled](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62644218)

Comment: Actually, I have this problem dealing with v.2.0. I plan to move to v.3.0 soon.
However, several users having so-called 'pages' attached to their accounts can do this just fine. That was a few months ago and now I can't remember if it is still reproducible.